# ASP.NET Core две операции над одним контекстом

Tags: многопоточность, asp.net-core, исключения

Есть такой код:

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    private readonly WarhammerContext _context;

    public CategoriesController(WarhammerContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult ProductListing()
    {

        var listingContext = _context.Product.Include(p => p.ProductFraction).Include(p => p.ProductType);            
        Dictionary<int, string> productImages = GetImagesByIds(listingContext.Select(p => p.Id));      
        foreach(var productId in productImages.Keys)
        {
            listingContext.Where(p => p.Id == productId).FirstOrDefault().ImageSource = productImages[productId];
        }
        ProductsViewModel pvm = new ProductsViewModel { ImageSources = productImages, Products = listingContext };

        return View(pvm);
    }


    public Dictionary<int, string> GetImagesByIds(IEnumerable<int> productIds) =>          
            _context.ProductImage.Where(p => productIds.Contains(p.Id)).ToDictionary(key => key.ProductId, value => value.ImageSource);




}
```

Выдает такое исключение:
"A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Пытался сделать так:

```
        {
            using (var context = new WarhammerContext())
            {
                return context.ProductImage.Where(p => productIds.Contains(p.Id)).ToDictionary(key => key.ProductId, value => value.ImageSource);
            }
        }
```

Но тогда в ProductListing словарь productImages становится null. В дебаггере выдает ошибку, потому что он диспозится. Как можно решить проблему?

Еще пробовал сделать AddTransient, но тоже не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте забрать данные сразу, а не передавать их внутрь функции: `var listingContext = ....Select(p => p.Id).ToList();`.

Comment: Да, теперь все работает, спасибо!

Comment: Хорошо, значит проблема во времени, когда запрос реально выполняется. Тогда добавляют ответ с пояснением, почему так произошло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам EntityFramework имеет ленивую модель вычисления и возвращает реальные данные только тогда, когда это необходимо. В вашем случае вы составляете запрос на выборку первых данных, но сами данные на самом деле еще не выбрались. Это только подготовка.

```
var listingContext = _context.Product.Include(p => p.ProductFraction).Include(p => p.ProductType).Select(p => p.Id);
```

Дальше вы передаете первый запрос в функцию, где формируется второй запрос. В итоге у вас два запроса, которые еще не запросили свои данные из-за ленивой модели. Второй запрос начинает вытягивать реальные данные, натыкается на первый и запускает его. В итоге вы получаете два одновременно выполняющихся запроса и EntityFramework валится с ошибкой.

При составлении запросов надо учитывать данную особенность ленивых вычислений. Можно решить проблему, написав принудительный ToList() и тогда данные будут получены сразу же.

```
var listingContext =  
    _context.Product.Include(p => p.ProductFraction).Include(p => p.ProductType).Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
```